# how to instruct python to ignore imports

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

i have a private module, which for better or worse, i've called `time`.
i have another module, which i've called `graph` that resides in the same directory it uses the `redis-py` module.

unfortunately, my `time` module doesn't do exactly what the standard `time` module does, and as a result i get the following error:

```
$ /opt/stuff/bin/python /opt/stuff/lib/utils/graph.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/stuff/lib/utils/graph.py", line 6, in <module>
    import redis
  File "/opt/stuff/lib/python2.6/site-packages/redis/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from redis.client import Redis, StrictRedis
  File "/opt/stuff/lib/python2.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 6, in <module>
    import time as mod_time
  File "/opt/stuff/lib/utils/time.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pytz
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import resource_stream
  File "/opt/stuff/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 761, in <module>
    class Environment(object):
  File "/opt/stuff/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 764, in Environment
    def __init__(self, search_path=None, platform=get_supported_platform(), python=PY_MAJOR):
  File "/opt/stuff/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 140, in get_supported_platform
    plat = get_build_platform(); m = macosVersionString.match(plat)
  File "/opt/stuff/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 282, in get_build_platform
    from distutils.util import get_platform
  File "/opt/stuff/lib64/python2.6/distutils/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from distutils import dist, sysconfig
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 21, in <module>
    from distutils.fancy_getopt import FancyGetopt, translate_longopt
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/fancy_getopt.py", line 32, in <module>
    longopt_xlate = string.maketrans('-', '_')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'
```

removing my `time` module rectifies the error. is there a way i can hack up my `graph.py` to basically ignore my `time` module and use the system one? i've tried using `from __future__ import absolute_import` but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: This is more than just your `time` module, there's another module named `string` that is in the way.

Comment: You'll have to rename the module, there is no way you can tell other modules to switch to absolute imports.

Answer (score 1):

It is not your `graph` module that is importing `time`; it is `redis.client` that does.

Your `time` is *also* a top-level module. Other Python code has no means to distinguish between your module and the standard library version.

You could alter the `sys.path` order and make sure standard library modules are found first, but really you should just rename your module. It is easy enough to give it a different name.